# Getting Papers based on certain keyword from microsoft academic

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

How can we get id of papers based on keyword.
e.g to get all paper ids of computer science from Microsoft Academic API
Microsoft academic 
graph search API

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, I assume you mean "field of study" for computer science.

Please, try this query:

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(F.FN='computer science')&model=latest&attributes=Id
```

Currently, values of attribute "W" (keyword) are single words, therefore in order to get both "computer" and "science" you need to use And() query.
See example below (I added "Ti" [title] attribute to output):

```
https://api.projectoxford.ai/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=And(W='computer', W='science')&model=latest&attributes=Id,Ti
```

Please, note that you need to specify "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" field in header of HTTP request, the value should be your subscription id.